# Disable datasheet/Quick Edit mode in SP 2013 on all views but one

Tags: 2013, permissions, datasheet, quick-edit

Is there a proper way to do this in SP 2013?
In 2010, you could just create your datasheet view and then click "disable editing in datasheet view" to prevent regular views from being converted. An upgrade to 2013 has caused some security (by obscurity..) to go away on certain sites that relied upon having this one view as an "Admin" view that only certain users can see and edit in bulk.

I know I could probably use a content editor with some CSS to hide the two "Quick Edit" links, but I was hoping there might be a better way.